# How to store many lists in one session?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Have ASP.NET Page with "ID" parameter:

I want to store a List of My class in the session depending on "ID" parameter,

```
public List<MyClass> list
{
    get
    {
        if (Session["SessionName"] == null)
        {
            Session["SessionName"] = new List<MyClass>();
        }
        return Session["SessionName"] as List<MyClass>;
    }
    set
    {
        Session["SessionName"] = value;
    }
}
```

I Mean:
when "ID" = 1 some values will store in the list,
when "ID" = 2 another values will store in the list
.
.
.

Why I do that?
Because end user can view the same page in many browser tabs with different "ID" values

Comment: Store complete list in session and then you can fetch the value from session list depending on the ID

Comment: what about "ID" has the same value in tow tabs?

Comment: thank you "Rohit Vyas", I want different list for every tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a dictionary instead of a list?

```
public Dictionary<int, List<MyClass>> list
{
    get
    {
        if (Session["SessionName"] == null)
        {
            Session["SessionName"] = new Dictionary<int, List<MyClass>>();
        }
        return Session["SessionName"] as Dictionary<int, List<MyClass>>;
    }
    set
    {
        Session["SessionName"] = value;
    }
}
```

In this way you can fetch it like this:

```
List<MyClass> l = list[1]
```

Comment: thank you "Patrick Hofman", I want different list for every tab ( may "ID" has "0" value in many pages)?

Comment: @asp.netprogrammer: the dictionary contains a list, so you can have multiple values there.